# ST_AsLatLonText gives error 'ERROR: Cannot convert an empty point into formatted text.'

Tags: postgis, postgresql

My SQL query below, is trying to get this data from my `mpoly` (which is just a geometry field in my database).

I can select and grab things and there are no null mpoly entries yet running this:

```
SELECT zone_id, mpoly, St_AsText(ST_Centroid(mpoly)), ST_AsLatLonText(ST_Centroid(mpoly), 'DDMMSS') as dms from swsite_cesiumentity where zone_id is null
```

`ERROR: Cannot convert an empty point into formatted text`

I guess to me this error is confusing since `mpoly` has no null fields, am I missing something in my select I guess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is referring not to a null geometry, but to an *empty* geometry, a distinction that can be a source of much confusion.

If the input to `ST_AsLatLonText` is empty, then it must be possible for `ST_Centroid` to generate an empty point.  Indeed, it turns out `ST_Centroid` produces an empty point, given an empty polygon:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid('POLYGON EMPTY'));
-- POINT EMPTY
```

So you have an empty polygon somewhere in your data.  You can find it using `ST_IsEmpty`.

Where might an empty polygon come from?  Lots of places, but one common example is a negative buffer that collapses a polygon into itself, like this:

```
ST_Buffer('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))', -2)
```

Comment: Three records had empty items, I removed them and my function worked. Thanks!